# Scala : Hide two class behind a generic one

Tags: scala

I have two different scala class that we can call ClassA and ClassB.

Let's also say that I have to function doSomething(ClassA) and doSomething(ClassB)

I want to create a new class ClassC that can be construct either from a ClassA or a ClassB and implement a function doSomething.

My problem is that I'm not really familiar with the Scala constructors (I'm more a Java developer) and I don't feel like what I am doing is right. Here is my try :

```
class ClassC(obj:Object,tmp:Integer) {

  def this(classA: ClassA){
    this(classA,0)
  }

  def this(classB: ClassB){
    this(classB,0)
  }

  def doSomething(){
    if(obj.getClass.getName == "ClassA"){
          // do something with obj
    }else if(obj.getClass.getName == "ClassB"){
          // do something with obj
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change `ClassA` and `ClassB`? Choosing the actions with `if - else` resembles the tagged anti-pattern. There could have been a `trait C { def doSomething(arg: Integer) }` that both `ClassA` and `ClassB` implement, without the need to wrap them into `ClassC`.

Comment: No, I'm not allowed to change ClassA and ClassB as they come from external libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal way to do so would be to create a common trait/abstract class and two classes extending it, one of which can be constructed from `ClassA` and another from `ClassB`:

```
trait TraitC {
  def doSomething(): Unit
}
object TraitC {
  def apply(x: ClassA) = ClassCA(x)
  def apply(x: ClassB) = ClassCB(x)
}

class ClassCA(x: ClassA) extends TraitC {
  def doSomething() = doSomething(x)
}
class ClassCB(x: ClassB) extends TraitC {
  def doSomething() = doSomething(x)
}
```

Much better than anything using `obj.getClass.getName`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Either` and capture the two cases

```
class A {
  def foo: Int = 1
}

class B {
  def foo: Int = 2
}
```

Lets say A and B cannot be changed and are available from some lib.

Create a class `Delegator`

```
case class Delegator(delegations: Either[A, B]) {
 def foo: Int = delegations.fold(_.foo, _.foo)
}
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


class A {
  def foo: Int = 1
}

class B {
  def foo: Int = 2
}

case class Delegator(delegations: Either[A, B]) {
 def foo: Int = delegations.fold(_.foo, _.foo)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined class B
defined class Delegator


scala> Delegator(Left(new A())).foo
res1: Int = 1


scala> Delegator(Right(new B())).foo
res3: Int = 2
```

With `apply` method, syntax gets even better

```
case class Delegator(delegations: Either[A, B]) {
 def apply(): Int = delegations.fold(_.foo, _.foo)
}
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

 case class Delegator(delegations: Either[A, B]) {
     def apply(): Int = delegations.fold(_.foo, _.foo)
    }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Delegator

scala> Delegator(Right(new B()))()
res6: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Either to make it work.

```
class ClassA {
  def operation = "Child1"
}
class ClassB  {
  def operation = "Child2"
}

class Op1(l: Either[ClassA, ClassB]) {
  def operation(): String = {
    l.fold(_.operation,_.operation)
  }
}

new Op1(Left(new ClassA)).operation()
new Op1(Right(new ClassB)).operation()
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to change ClassA and ClassB as they come from external libs, so I can't use this solution.